# figurename (captionname) changing

Tags: floats, captions

I have a problem with my algorithms, I'm using the mcode-package: I would like the caption to say Algorithmus 1.1 for example. If I try it with a figure environment it does not work, because I don't have a pagebrak, when my algorithm ist very long. So, I googled, and came up with this solution:

```
\documentclass[german,11pt,twoside,a4paper,final,titlepage,openany]{amsbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy,amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{mcode}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}

function y = PolyValMatrix(p,x) 
    y = zeros(size(p,1),size(x,1));
    xt = x';
    for i = 1:size(p,2)
        n = size(p,2)-i;
        y = y + p(:,i)*(xt.^n);
    end
end

\end{lstlisting}
\renewcommand*\figurename{Algorithmus}
\captionof{figure}{Algorithmus}\label{algo:875}

\end{document}
```

But the problem is: Once I insert another figure after this, it also calls it Algorithmus, and not Abbildung (figure) how I would like it.

Can anyone please help me? Sorry for the german words :)

Edit: This one is running correctly:

```
 \documentclass[german,11pt,twoside,a4paper,final,titlepage,openany]{amsbook}
 \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    
 \usepackage{graphicx}               %% don't use [pdftex]
 \usepackage{mathrsfs,amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsbsy,amsmath}
 \usepackage{float}
 %\usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage[framed,numbered]{mcode}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithmus}}  %% Use this since
                                                               %%  you are using babel
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[float=htb,
                caption={Algorithmus\label{algo:875}},
                %captionpos=b    %% if you want caption below
                ]

function y = PolyValMatrix(p,x)
y = zeros(size(p,1),size(x,1));
xt = x';
    for i = 1:size(p,2)
    n = size(p,2)-i;
    y = y + p(:,i)*(xt.^n);
    end
end

\end{lstlisting}

Here we refer~\ref{algo:875}


\end{document}
```

And this one isn't, but in my eyes it's exactly the same, apart from the not using float (but that doesn't make a difference...)

```
  \documentclass[german,11pt,twoside,a4paper,final,titlepage,openany]{amsbook}
  \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{mathrsfs,amssymb}
  \usepackage{amsbsy,amsmath}
  \usepackage{float}
  %\usepackage{subcaption}
  \usepackage[framed,numbered]{mcode}
  \addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithmus}}  %% Use this since

  \begin{document}
  Here we refer ~\ref{algo:875}
  \begin{lstlisting}[%float=htb,
                caption={Algorithmus\label{algo:875}},
                captionpos=b    %% if you want caption below
                      ]
  %Benötigte Funktionen
  function y = PolyValMatrix(p,x) 
      y = zeros(size(p,1),size(x,1));  
  xt = x';
  for i = 1:size(p,2)
        n = size(p,2)-i;
       y = y + p(:,i)*(xt.^n);

    end
end

\end{lstlisting}

Here we refer ~\ref{algo:875}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put the redefinition in a group, or rather define a new environment, which can be done with `tocbasic`.

Comment: Please also have a look at [GoLaTeX](http://www.golatex.de/laengere-matlab-codes-in-latex-einbinden-t12769.html), a german forum.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but you guys here always help me so fast :-) But if I do this as a new environment, I would have to choose figure for this as well, which would lead to my previous problem...Could you maybe be more specific?

Comment: Not begin another figure environment, but *define* a new one. Please see the link to golatex.

Comment: You can also give a caption to the `lstlisting` environment

Answer (score 4):

`mcode` internally uses `listings` to typeset matlab codes. Hence you can add a caption using `listings` itself.

```
\documentclass[german,11pt,twoside,a4paper,final,titlepage,openany]{amsbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}               %% don't use [pdftex]
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy,amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{mcode}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algorithmus}}  %% Use this since
                                                                   %%  you are using babel
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[float=htb,
                    caption={Algorithmus},
                    label={algo:875},
                    %captionpos=b    %% if you want caption below
                    ]

function y = PolyValMatrix(p,x)
    y = zeros(size(p,1),size(x,1));
    xt = x';
    for i = 1:size(p,2)
        n = size(p,2)-i;
        y = y + p(:,i)*(xt.^n);
    end
end

\end{lstlisting}

Here we refer~\ref{algo:875}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great,thanks for your help,that's exactly what I'm looking for! But there is a weird problem: My reference doesn't work: For me it doesn't say 1, it says 11. And in my original document it says 70. But when I click on that number it goes straight to the right spot... Do you know what that's about?

Comment: @Nina Glad it works. But I am getting the references correct. Can you compile 1-2 times more and see if it works? Also, did you run my exact code above. Note the `\addto\captionsngerman` command.

Comment: Ok, this is weird, or I am blind. I have one, that is running correctly and one that isn't. I will post both examples in my original post.

Comment: @Nina OK, my fault. Use `caption={Algorithmus},label={algo:875},`. This is the label command provided by `listings`. It works.  I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, great, it works for me too! But it's weird though, that one time it works, one time it doesn't...Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Nina With `label` from `listings`, it always works. And BTW, thanks are conveyed here in this site by upvoting and accepting the answers that helped you. For details see: [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)